# git checkout only modified files from another branch into current

Tags: git

I'm fairly new to Git and here's my situation:

- I have a master development repo for the purposes of making a website.
- I have a branch of that repo which is dedicated only to files I want to upload to the server.  (A subset of the master files)
- I want to develop in the master branch, then when I'm ready, checkout the newest versions of the server files from the master branch to the server branch.

I realize I can `git checkout master file_paths`  but it would be nice if git could

1. See what files exist in the server branch
2. Check out the newest versions of those files from the master branch.

Is there a way to do this?  Or a better (faster) workflow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git ls-files | sed 's/.*/git checkout master -- "&"/' | sh -x
```

or (what was I thinking)

```
git ls-files | xargs git checkout master --
```

Comment: my apologies, the original had the wrong syntax.  This one works.

Comment: @Josh - I reverted your edit because there's no bash-ism in there.  Is there some specific shell this won't work on?

Comment: These command won't work under a Windows shell.  The question is tagged [git]

Comment: Hm. I think POSIX shell is a given.  Git ships with one, so there's always one available if you've actually got git.  I've pointed out GNU extensions before, I don't think git depends on any bashisms, but I can't remember anyone pointing out they're using a POSIX shell here where Windows wasn't already part of the conversation somehow.  Can you point me to some examples?